# Azure ML experiment run failing with 'HttpLoggingPolicy' has no attribute 'DEFAULT_HEADERS_ALLOWLIST'

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azuremlsdk

This is related to the azure experiment run in the Microsoft Azure Machine Learning Studio.
The experiment run fails with this stack trace:

```
Warning: Failed to setup Azure Machine Learning system code due to `type object 'HttpLoggingPolicy' has no attribute 'DEFAULT_HEADERS_ALLOWLIST'`. Your job will proceed but if you notice any issues, please contact Azure Support with this exception message.
/azureml-envs/pytorch-1.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/_tracking_service/utils.py:213: UserWarning: Failure attempting to register store for scheme "adbazureml": type object 'HttpLoggingPolicy' has no attribute 'DEFAULT_HEADERS_ALLOWLIST'
  _tracking_store_registry.register_entrypoints()
/azureml-envs/pytorch-1.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/_tracking_service/utils.py:213: UserWarning: Failure attempting to register store for scheme "azureml": type object 'HttpLoggingPolicy' has no attribute 'DEFAULT_HEADERS_ALLOWLIST'
  _tracking_store_registry.register_entrypoints()
/azureml-envs/pytorch-1.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/artifact_repository_registry.py:93: UserWarning: Failure attempting to register artifact repository for scheme "adbazureml": type object 'HttpLoggingPolicy' has no attribute 'DEFAULT_HEADERS_ALLOWLIST'
  _artifact_repository_registry.register_entrypoints()
/azureml-envs/pytorch-1.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/artifact_repository_registry.py:93: UserWarning: Failure attempting to register artifact repository for scheme "azureml": type object 'HttpLoggingPolicy' has no attribute 'DEFAULT_HEADERS_ALLOWLIST'
  _artifact_repository_registry.register_entrypoints()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "azure_ml_pipeline.py", line 7, in <module>
    from interface import step_factory
  File "/mnt/azureml/cr/j/e54eb5aef8a648e7bfb46dc654434eca/exe/wd/interface.py", line 3, in <module>
    from steps.evaluation import Evaluation
  File "/mnt/azureml/cr/j/e54eb5aef8a648e7bfb46dc654434eca/exe/wd/steps/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from utils.data_container import DataContainer
  File "/mnt/azureml/cr/j/e54eb5aef8a648e7bfb46dc654434eca/exe/wd/utils/data_container.py", line 1, in <module>
    from azureml.core import Dataset
  File "/azureml-envs/pytorch-1.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/core/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .workspace import Workspace
  File "/azureml-envs/pytorch-1.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/core/workspace.py", line 22, in <module>
    from azureml._project import _commands
  File "/azureml-envs/pytorch-1.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/_project/_commands.py", line 24, in <module>
    from azureml._workspace._utils import (
  File "/azureml-envs/pytorch-1.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/_workspace/_utils.py", line 10, in <module>
    from azure.mgmt.storage import StorageManagementClient
  File "/azureml-envs/pytorch-1.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/mgmt/storage/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ._storage_management_client import StorageManagementClient
  File "/azureml-envs/pytorch-1.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/mgmt/storage/_storage_management_client.py", line 14, in <module>
    from azure.mgmt.core import ARMPipelineClient
  File "/azureml-envs/pytorch-1.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/mgmt/core/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from ._pipeline_client import ARMPipelineClient
  File "/azureml-envs/pytorch-1.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/mgmt/core/_pipeline_client.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .policies import ARMAutoResourceProviderRegistrationPolicy, ARMHttpLoggingPolicy
  File "/azureml-envs/pytorch-1.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/mgmt/core/policies/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    class ARMHttpLoggingPolicy(HttpLoggingPolicy):
  File "/azureml-envs/pytorch-1.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/mgmt/core/policies/__init__.py", line 43, in ARMHttpLoggingPolicy
    DEFAULT_HEADERS_ALLOWLIST = HttpLoggingPolicy.DEFAULT_HEADERS_ALLOWLIST | set(
AttributeError: type object 'HttpLoggingPolicy' has no attribute 'DEFAULT_HEADERS_ALLOWLIST'
```

Does anyone facing the issue recently know the fix for it?

Answer (score 3):

I tried the below code with the azure.core.pipeline.policies and HttpLoggingPolicy with azure core version set to - ***azure-core              1.26.4*** ***which is the latest version and I did not receive attribute error on HttpLoggingPolicy .***

**Code:-**

```py
from azure.core.pipeline import PipelineRequest
from azure.core.pipeline.policies import HttpLoggingPolicy

policy = HttpLoggingPolicy.DEFAULT_HEADERS_ALLOWLIST
print(policy)
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

My azure-core version after running `pip list` :-

[image]

HttpLoggingPolicy was added in # azure-core version 1.16.0. If you are using older version than 1.16.0 you will receive attribute not found error. Make sure you upgrade your azure-core version to the latest release like below:-

```py
pip install azure-core==1.26.4
```

> According to this link document-  [azure-core ·
> PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/azure-core/1.16.0/#description) and the point below from the above link document: -
> 1.7.0 (2020-07-06) -
>
> - Added  `http_logging_policy`  property on the  `Configuration`  object, allowing users to individually set the http logging policy of
>   the config #12218

Comment: It did work after upgrading all azure dependencies. I had `azure-core==1.24.1` when I got those exceptions. These worked for me:
                `azure-core==1.26.4` 
                `azureml-core==1.50.0`
                `azureml-defaults==1.50.0`